# Vb.net 2 decimals double

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, format, double

I want to place all my doubles to 2 decimals after the comma. 
At this moment when the value is 0.30, my Datagridview shows 0.3..any idea?

This is my code:

```
    eenheidsprijs = Math.Round(eenheidsprijs, 2)
    basisbedrag = Math.Round(basisbedrag, 2)
    kortingbedrag = Math.Round(kortingbedrag, 2)
    netto = Math.Round(netto, 2)
    btwbedrag = Math.Round(btwbedrag, 2)
    totaal = Math.Round(totaal, 2)

    Dim streenheidsprijs, strbasisbedrag, strkortingbedrag, strnetto, strbtwbedrag, strtotaal As String

    streenheidsprijs = Format(eenheidsprijs, "0.00")
    strbasisbedrag = Format(basisbedrag, "0.00")
    strkortingbedrag = Format(kortingbedrag, "0.00")
    strnetto = Format(netto, "0.00")
    strbtwbedrag = btwbedrag.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    strtotaal = Format(totaal, "0.00")


    eenheidsprijs = Double.Parse(streenheidsprijs)
    basisbedrag = Double.Parse(strbasisbedrag)
    kortingbedrag = Double.Parse(strkortingbedrag)
    netto = Double.Parse(strnetto)
    btwbedrag = Double.Parse(strbtwbedrag)
    totaal = Double.Parse(strtotaal)
```

Comment: may i know what will be your expected out put?

Comment: no need to convert numeric => string => numeric `String.Format` and `.ToString` can be used to display a numeric in a specified format.  The DGV also has built in formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy(v=vs.110).aspx) to the [default cell style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) of the [column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format(v=vs.110).aspx). In your case, the format `F2` would be preferable.

*At run-time:*

```vb
myDataGridView.Columns("myColumnName").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "F2"
```

*At design-time:*

[image]

**Sample form**

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.ClientSize = New Size(350, 400)
        Me.column1 = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = "Column1", .HeaderText = "Double (F2)", .ValueType = GetType(Double), .Width = 100}
        Me.column1.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "F2"
        Me.column2 = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With {.Name = "Column2", .HeaderText = "Double (F8)", .ValueType = GetType(Double), .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill, .MinimumWidth = 100}
        Me.column2.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "F8"
        Me.grid = New DataGridView With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
        Me.grid.Columns.AddRange(Me.column1, Me.column2)
        For i As Double = 0.0R To 9.0R : Me.grid.Rows.Add(i, i) : Next
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.grid)
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents grid As DataGridView
    Private WithEvents column1 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Private WithEvents column2 As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

End Class
```

[image]

Comment: `Not working` tells me **nothing**. Update your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: Excuses, I was in a hurry..I tried this solution but no succes. It's still 0.3 instead of 0.30 :s...I found an other solution but also no succes (        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n2"
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).ValueType = GetType(Double))

Comment: @user3388946 I've added a sample form. Unless you edit your question (refer to my previous comment), then this is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Which value is bound to your datagrid? streenheidsprijs or eenheidsprijs? The string value is formatted to 2 decimal places, but the double variable doesn't inherit the number of decimal places to show. In actual fact, there is no value in the lines to re-parse the string values that have been formatted:

```
eenheidsprijs = Double.Parse(streenheidsprijs)
```

The data grid columns should either be bound to the string values that have been formatted to 2 dp, or you should configure the display properties of the columns in the data grid so that they only show two decimal places.